# can't perform GCD i/o for files

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I need to load and write images asynchronously - but i can't access the file if it is writing now. For this purposes I want to use barrier_async for write and sync for read files. Here is my code:

The part of the block method to perform gcd operations:

```
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:
     ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {   
         [self.class writeData:data toFilePath:tileFilePathName completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     [[AxPanoramaDataManager sharedInstance].tilesNamesArray addObject:tileFileName];
                 });
                 [self.class readImagefromFilePath:tileFilePathName
                                 completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                                     if (!error)
                                         dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                             completion(tileCoordValue, side, image, error);
                                         });
                                 }];
             }
         }];
     }];
```

and read/write methods:

```
+ (void) readImagefromFilePath: (NSString *) filePath
             completionHandler:(void (^)(UIImage* image, NSError* error)) handler
{
    dispatch_sync([AxPanoramaDataManager sharedInstance].dataManagerQueue, ^{
        UIImage *tileImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            handler(tileImage, nil);
            NSLog(@"Image %@ loaded from cash", tileImage);
        });
    });
}

+ (void) writeData: (NSData *) data
        toFilePath: (NSString *) filePath
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError* error)) handler
{
    dispatch_barrier_async([AxPanoramaDataManager sharedInstance].dataManagerQueue, ^{
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            handler(nil);
            NSLog(@"Data %@ wrote to the disk", data);
        });
    });
}
```

Now the app is hanging while I try to perform this method. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're deadlocking yourself. Here's that code "unrolled" to be a single call. (I'll break it apart below.)

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    // Unroll: [self.class writeData: data toFilePath: filePath completionHandler: writeDataCompletion];
    dispatch_barrier_async(dataManagerQueue, ^{
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Unroll: writeDataCompletion(nil);
            NSError* error = nil;
            if (!error) {
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [[AxPanoramaDataManager sharedInstance].tilesNamesArray addObject:tileFileName];
                });

                // Unroll: [self.class readImagefromFilePath:tileFilePathName completionHandler:readCompletion];
                dispatch_sync(dataManagerQueue, ^{
                    UIImage *tileImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        // Unroll: readCompletion(tileImage, nil);
                        NSError* error = nil;
                        if (!error) {
                            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                completion(tileCoordValue, side, tileImage, error);
                            });
                        }
                        NSLog(@"Image %@ loaded from cash", tileImage);
                    });
                });
            }
            NSLog(@"Data %@ wrote to the disk", data);
        });
    });
}];
```

Now let's trace through it line by line, noting what thread/queue we're on at each phase:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
```

OK, so when you get into the callback from `-[NSURLConnection sendAsync...]` you're on the main thread, because you passed `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` to the `queue:` parameter.

```
    // Unroll: [self.class writeData: data toFilePath: filePath completionHandler: writeDataCompletion];
    dispatch_barrier_async(dataManagerQueue, ^{
```

Now we're on `dataManagerQueue`, in a barrier block, which means that until we return from this block, nothing else can run on `dataManagerQueue`. Because the barrier call is async, we expect the main thread/queue to be free at this point.

```
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

Now we're back on the main queue. Note that because this was called with `dispatch_sync` we are *also* still in the barrier block on `dataManagerQueue`.

```
            // Unroll: writeDataCompletion(nil);
            NSError* error = nil;
            if (!error) {
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

We were already on the main queue, so `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()` is going to deadlock here. We're dead in the water at this point, but let's keep going anyway, and assume for the moment that `dispatch_sync` handles recursive re-entry (it doesn't, but...)

```
                    [[AxPanoramaDataManager sharedInstance].tilesNamesArray addObject:tileFileName];
                });

                // Unroll: [self.class readImagefromFilePath:tileFilePathName completionHandler:readCompletion];
                dispatch_sync(dataManagerQueue, ^{
```

Now, notice that we're still in the barrier block that you submitted to `dataManagerQueue` but we're attempting to submit another block via `dispatch_sync(dataManagerQueue, ...)`. So if we weren't already deadlocked on the main queue above, now we would be deadlocked on `dataManagerQueue`.

```
                    UIImage *tileImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

And now we're synchronously re-entering the main queue *again*!

```
                        // Unroll: readCompletion(tileImage, nil);
                        NSError* error = nil;
                        if (!error) {
                            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

And **again**!!!

```
                                completion(tileCoordValue, side, tileImage, error);
                            });
                        }
                        NSLog(@"Image %@ loaded from cash", tileImage);
                    });
                });
            }
            NSLog(@"Data %@ wrote to the disk", data);
        });
    });
}];
```

In short, you have *numerous* deadlocks here. You seem to be using `dispatch_sync` in many places where you could be using `dispatch_async` but I can't possibly know what else is in play that made you think all these completions need to be fired synchronously. Based on the code you posted, you could start by turning every `_sync` call into an `_async` call with no substantive ill effects (i.e. the only effect visible from the code posted here would be that the `NSLog`s will fire at different times.)

Another general rule of thumb is that `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` is almost always a bad idea. (See [detailed explanation](http://tomdalling.com/blog/cocoa/gotchas-with-grand-central-dispatch-libdispatch-and-blocks/)) Even if it works "most of the time" it is problematic, because things out of your control (i.e. in the OS) could interact with that pattern in a way that can cause a deadlock. You probably want to rework anywhere you rely on a `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` to be a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ... )` followed by a nested re-dispatching of the remaining background work to a background queue. But generally speaking, most main thread completions should be able to be dispatched asynchronously without an issue.

Comment: very big thanks! I'll try to rewrite this ugly method using your comments. Thanks for detailed explanation!